# Promise function is not running funcation after .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, promise, aws-lambda

What I am trying to do is run functions that will send out messages. The problem with node js is that it does not return in sequence. I do however want each function to run in the sequence that it is coded.

Not really sure what I'm missing here.

Right now I can get it to return only message 1 and message 2 in sequence BUT I want to go all the way from callfirstmessage to callfifthmessage. When I have tried to do this they all get returned out of order.

```js
var promise = new Promises(function(resolve, reject) {
  // do some async stuff
  callfirstmessage();
  //resolve(data);
  if (success) {
    resolve(data);
  } else {
    reject(reason);
  }
});
promise.then(function(data) {
  // function called when first promise returned
  return new Promises(function(resolve, reject) {
    // second async stuff
    callthirdmessage();
    //resolve(data);
    if (success) {
      resolve(data);
    } else {
      reject(reason);
    }
  });
}, function(reason) {
  // error handler
}).then(function(data) {
  callsecondmessage();

}, function(reason) {
  // second error handler
});
```

I have looked at a few different posts talking about this topic and I have used those suggestions. I think my issue here is not being able to successfully chain these together. I have spent a few days on this with no additional progress...I need help bad!

-----------------------edit----------------------------

I think I need to apply something similar to this .then I have found here: https://coderwall.com/p/ijy61g/promise-chains-with-node-js. But for some reason it is still sending messages at random.

Maybe, I'm just going in the completely wrong direction. :/

Below is everything I am working with

```js
// dependencies
console.log("starting program");
var async = require('async');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var util = require('util');
var Promises = require('pinkie-promise');
var vow = require('vow');

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var snsTopicEMAIL = new AWS.SNS({
  params: {
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
});
var snsTopicSMS = new AWS.SNS({
  params: {
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  }
});

var abort = false;

//SMS
function topDSRsms(csvJSON) {
  var ytdTopReg = "";

  if (csvJSON.length < 1) {
    console.error("Not enough data records in CSV to compose an SMS. Aborting. count:" + csvJSON.length);
    tdTopReg = "There was an error. Please contact IT for assistance.";
    abort = true;
    throw '';
  }

  ytdTopReg = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < csvJSON.length; i++) {
    var csvItem = csvJSON;
    if (csvItem[i].KPIvalue.length > 0 && csvItem[i].KPI.length > 0) {
      var KPI = " " + csvItem[i].KPI + ":" + csvItem[i].KPIvalue + "\n";
    } else {
      KPI = " ";
    }
    if (csvItem[i].TrendValue1.length > 0 && csvItem[i].Trend1.length > 0) {
      var trend1 = "\n" + svItem[i].Trend1 + ":" + csvItem[i].csvItem[i].TrendValue1;
    } else {
      trend1 = "";
    }
    if (csvItem[i].TrendValue2.length > 0 && csvItem[i].Trend2.length > 0) {
      var trend2 = "\n" + csvItem[i].Trend2 + ":" + csvItem[i].TrendValue2;
    } else {
      trend2 = "";
    }
    if (csvItem[i].TrendValue3.length > 0 && csvItem[i].Trend3.length > 0) {
      var trend3 = "\n" + csvItem[i].Trend3 + ":" + csvItem[i].TrendValue3;
    } else {
      trend3 = "";
    }
    ytdTopReg += "\n#" + (i + 1) + KPI + csvItem[i].RankTrend + ":" + csvItem[i].RankTrendValue + trend1 + trend2 + trend3;
  }
  return ytdTopReg;
}

function dshSmsStr(csvJSON) {
  return "DSR:" +
    topDSRsms(csvJSON);
}

//email
function topDSREmail(csvJSON) {
  var ytdTopReg = "";

  ytdTopReg = "Top orders By Region - ";
  for (var i = 0; i < csvJSON.length; i++) {

    if (csvJSON.length < 1) {
      console.error("Not enough data records in CSV to compose an email. Aborting.");
      ytdTopReg = "There was an error. Please contact IT for assistance."
      abort = true;
      throw '';
      //return -1;
    } else {
      var csvItem = csvJSON;
      if (csvItem[i].KPIvalue.length > 0 && csvItem[i].KPI.length > 0) {
        var KPI = " " + csvItem[i].KPI + ":" + csvItem[i].KPIvalue + "\n";
      } else {
        KPI = "";
      }
      if (csvItem[i].TrendValue1.length > 0 && csvItem[i].Trend1.length > 0) {
        var trend1 = "\n" + svItem[i].Trend1 + ":" + csvItem[i].csvItem[i].TrendValue1;
      } else {
        trend1 = "";
      }
      if (csvItem[i].TrendValue2.length > 0 && csvItem[i].Trend2.length > 0) {
        var trend2 = "\n" + csvItem[i].Trend2 + ":" + csvItem[i].TrendValue2;
      } else {
        trend2 = "";
      }
      if (csvItem[i].TrendValue3.length > 0 && csvItem[i].Trend3.length > 0) {
        var trend3 = "\n" + csvItem[i].Trend3 + ":" + csvItem[i].TrendValue3;
      } else {
        trend3 = "";
      }
      ytdTopReg += "\n#" + (i + 1) + KPI + csvItem[i].RankTrend + ":" + csvItem[i].RankTrendValue + trend1 + trend2 + trend3 + "\n";
    }
  }
  return ytdTopReg;
}

function dshEmailStr(csvJSON) {
  return "DSR:" +
    topDSREmail(csvJSON);
}
console.log("compiled totals string and customer string");
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  // Read options from the event.
  console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {
    depth: 5
  }));
  var srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  console.log("got src bucket name");
  // Object key may have spaces or unicode non-ASCII characters.
  var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
  console.log("src key decoded");
  // Download the CSV file from S3, Extract&Load data into DynamoDB, and notify end users.
  async.waterfall([
    function downloadCSV(next) {
      // Download the Daily Sales Highlights CSV file from S3 into a buffer.
      s3.getObject({
          Bucket: srcBucket,
          Key: srcKey
        },
        next);
    },

    function parseCSV(response, next) {
      console.log(response.ContentType);

      var csvStream = AWS.util.buffer.toStream(response.Body);
      var csvJSON = [];

      var converter = new Converter({});
      //end_parsed will be emitted once parsing finished 
      converter.on("end_parsed", function(jsonArray) {
        console.log(jsonArray); //here is your result jsonarray 
        csvJSON = jsonArray;
        next(null, csvJSON);
      });
      //read CSV from stream 
      csvStream.pipe(converter);
    },
    function updateState(csvJSON, next) {
      //Update state in DynamoDB
      next(null, csvJSON);
    },
    function notifyEndUsers(csvJSON, next) {

      //Notify end users
      console.log("\n\nNotifying SMS end users...\n\n");
      console.log(dshSmsStr(csvJSON));
      console.log("\n\nNotifying email end users...\n\n");
      console.log(dshEmailStr(csvJSON));

      //email
      snsTopicEMAIL.publish({
        Message: dshEmailStr(csvJSON)
      }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
          next(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        next(null);
      });


      //SMS
      var datastr = dshSmsStr(csvJSON);
      var strlen = dshSmsStr(csvJSON).length;
      var ranscript = false;
      var completemsg1 = false;
      var completemsg2 = false;
      var completemsg3 = false;
      var completemsg4 = false;
      var completemsg5 = false;
      var completemsg6 = false;

      function callfirstmessage() {
        snsTopicSMS.publish({
          Message: dshSmsStr(csvJSON).substring(0, 150)
        }, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            next(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
          next(null);
        });
        return true;
      }

      function callsecondmessage() {
        snsTopicSMS.publish({
          Message: dshSmsStr(csvJSON).substring(150, 300)
        }, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            next(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
          next(null);
        });
        return true;
      }

      function callthirdmessage() {
        snsTopicSMS.publish({
          Message: dshSmsStr(csvJSON).substring(300, 450)
        }, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            next(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
          next(null);
        });
        return true;
      }

      function callfourthmessage() {
        snsTopicSMS.publish({
          Message: dshSmsStr(csvJSON).substring(450, 600)
        }, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            next(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
          next(null);
        });
        return true;
      }

      function callfifthmessage() {
        snsTopicSMS.publish({
          Message: dshSmsStr(csvJSON).substring(600, 750)
        }, function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            next(err);
          }
          console.log(data);
          next(null);
        });
        return true;
      }

      function one() {
        new Promises(function(resolve1, reject) {
          completemsg1 = callfirstmessage();
          if (completemsg1 === true) {
            resolve1(true);
            console.log('first success');
          } else {
            reject(false);
            console.log('first fail');
          }

        });
      }

      function two() {
        new Promises(function(resolve2, reject) {
          completemsg2 = callsecondmessage();
          if (completemsg2 === true) {
            resolve2(completemsg2);
            console.log('second success');
          } else {
            reject(false);
            console.log('second fail');
          }

        });
      }

      function three() {
        new Promises(function(resolve3, reject) {
          completemsg3 = callthirdmessage();
          if (completemsg3 === true) {
            resolve3(completemsg3);
            console.log('third success');
          } else {
            reject(false);
            console.log('third fail');
          }

        });
      }

      function four() {
        new Promises(function(resolve4, reject) {
          completemsg4 = callfourthmessage();
          if (completemsg4 === true) {
            resolve4(completemsg4);
            console.log('fourth success');
          } else {
            reject(false);
            console.log('fourth fail');
          }

        });
      }

      function five() {
        new Promises(function(resolve5, reject) {
          completemsg5 = callfifthmessage();
          if (completemsg5 === true) {
            resolve5(completemsg5);
            console.log('fifth success');
          } else {
            reject(false);
            console.log('fifth fail');
          }

        });
      }
      console.log("\n\n Begin SMS script. Data length :" + strlen + "...\n\n");
      if (strlen < 150) { //one message sent
        //Will complete later
        ranscript = true;
      } else if (strlen < 300) { //two messages sent
        //Will complete later
        ranscript = true;
      } else if (strlen < 450) { //three messages sent
        //Will complete later
        ranscript = true;
      } else if (strlen < 600) { //four messages sent
        one().then(function() {
            return two();
          })
          .then(function() {
            return three();
          })
          .then(function() {
            return four();
          })
          .then(function() {
            return five();
          });
        ranscript = true;
      } else if (strlen < 750) { //five messages sent
        //Will complete later
        ranscript = true;
      } else {
        console.log("\n\n The SMS mesages is too large to send to end users...\n\n");
      }
      if (ranscript === false) {
        console.log("\n\n SMS script did not run \n\n");
      } else if (ranscript === true) {
        console.log("\n\n SMS script successfully ran \n\n");
      }
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(
        'Unable to process due to an error: ' + err
      );
    } else {
      console.log(
        'Successfully processed'
      );
    }

    context.done();
  });

}
```

Comment: `success` isn't defined anywhere. That will result in a reference error.

Comment: You have `Promises` plural...

Comment: are callfirstmessage and callsecondmessage synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: When you post code with typos in it and references to variables that don't exist and then don't respond when asked about those, there's not much we can do but close your question.

Comment: sorry all, I have made some updates.

also, Promises = require('promise');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The executor for the first promise (reformatted):

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
{ // do some async stuff
  callfirstmessage();
  if (success)
  { resolve(data);
  } else
  { reject(reason);
  }
});
```

doesn't resolve or reject the returned promise asynchronously. You will need to get a call back from the asynchronous operation before resolving/rejecting the returned promise. In pseudo code something more like:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
{ // do some async stuff
  callfirstmessage( successCallBack, failCallBack);
  function successCallBack( data)
  {  resolve(data);
  }
  function failCallBack( reason)
  {  reject(reason);
  }
});
```

In reality you may have to use a call back the asynchronous operation supports, and then analyze success or failure of the operation depending on a status property located in a request or response object.

Comment: This was helpful. I was able to get it to run callfirstmessage() and callsecondmessage() in order BUT none of the others after that will run in order. I've edited the code above to show what I have now.

Comment: Without detail it's hard to elaborate. Suggest try writing a function that takes details of a message to send (whether just the number of a set of numbered messages or more detail such as URL, request data and request type for a Post or Get) and returns a promise which fulfills with data returned successfully or rejects with an error that occurred. Don't use global variables and don't export details of how it is implemented to higher level Promise composition. Get that working and you can look at message composition ;-)